# Discord JSON command not firing

Tags: javascript, json, jscript, discord.js

Just working on a discord bot, and I'm loading a command but when I call it in chat it's not actually firing. It's a command to get a value from a sql database and paste it in chat, but it's just not firing at all.

COMMAND CODE

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, con) => {
    let target = message.mentions.user.first() || message.author;

    con.query(`SELECT * FROM xp WHERE id = '${target.id}'`, (err, rows) =>{
        if(err) throw err;

        let xp = rows[0].xp;
        message.channel.send(xp);
    });
}
```

Load commands

```
fs.readdir("./cmds/", (err, files) => {
    if(err) console.error(err);

    let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
    if(jsfiles.length <= 0) {
        console.log("No commands to load.");
        return;
    }

    console.log(`Loading ${jsfiles.length} commands.`)

    jsfiles.forEach((f, i) => {
        let props = require(`./cmds/${f}`);
        console.log(`${i + 1}: ${f} loaded.`)
        bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props)
    });
});
```

Comment: So you're saying your `run` function isn't firing, right? Where are you calling it?

Comment: Also what are you getting in your console log statements?